# Where can I find some tough creatures?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4

I need some foes to challenge a somewhat overpowered group.  Which SR4 supplement has some good foes for high end groups?

Comment: Does it not depend on the abilities and composition of the PC group as to what 'tough' means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you specifically want an enemy that would provide an interesting and difficult fight, rather than an interesting plot.

Then you'll find some nice treats in :

- Core Rulebook, check the dragons stats, they are quite the big boss in-universe
- Augmentations, which describes cyborgs (metahuman brain in a jar, rigged in a killing machine robot)
- Runner's companion give stats for vampires (also present in core rulebook) and others "monsters", but they're meant to be playable, so maybe not powerfull enough
- Street Magic, if you're looking for spirits (they have some real nice powers, especially if they can negate your party's mage). If they're really *that* high end, well, throw a god at them. A spirit with a Force 10 or 15 should be quite the challenge, if you're into rolling 30 dice at a time
- Unwired, if you're looking for a fight only a hacker could win (an infinite swarm of killing robot-wasp, produced by a factory gone wild...)

That said, numerous boss fights ends too quickly because in the end, one guy rarely is enough to beat several PCs, or is powerfull enough to one-shot an unlucky PC. A room [full of mooks](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WolfpackBoss) is generally a much better option if you want to challenge your party.

Comment: I'm looking for a creature that would provide an interesting and difficult fight, which I can shape to my plot.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to challenge a group is to copy their caracter sheets, give them different names and backstories and have this new group of NPCs be hired by someone to kill your current group. You won't find tougher enemies, there's a dozen man hours of optimization in this characters. Probably more than you will get from any book. And they are absolutely on their level. Even to the last karma point spent.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question.

Comment: The technically correct answer would be "Core Rulebook". It has all data to create deadly enemies for any kind of group. If you have special needs, maybe you can clarify them in your question. Are you looking for equipment, non-humans or a premade adventure with ready-made foes?

Comment: @quillbreaker it depends on what question you are actually asking.  If you want "foes to challenge a somewhat overpowered group" this is a great technique that I wish I had thought of a long time ago and will use in the future.  If you want a supplement that has monsters, look for a bestiary.  I haven't played 4th ed at all, but for 2nd edition they had Paranormal Animals of North America which had lost of fun critters.